# How do I avoid keypad during Scrolling?

Tags: java, android, testing, appium

I need to test the button which is below the text box and for that I need to scroll the screen as button is not visible. But when it starts Scrolling the screen,keypad appears (as the text box is editable) and hide the button and stop scrolling down. It happens on my Samsung S4 android phone (version 4.4.4) not on any other android device.

I am using appium (version 1.4.13.1) on my window machine.

try {
            ClickShareViaEmailBtn();

```
        if (panelShareObject.ShareTextBtn.isDisplayed()) {

            MobileUtils.navigateBack(driver);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        throw e;
    }
```

public void ClickShareViaEmailBtn() throws Throwable {

```
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        // Utils.sleep(ShareViaEmail, 20, driver);
        // Thread.sleep(1000);

        panelShareObject.ShareViaEmail.click();



        MobileUtils.swipeDown(driver);


    } catch (Throwable e) {
        MobileUtils.navigateBack(driver);
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please share the code, so that we can have more clarity on the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If the button is hidden by the keyboard, then you can first hide the keyboard and then click on the button.

Hide Keyboard -

```
driver.getKeyboard().sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
```

or

```
driver.hideKeyboard();
```